# Android keyboard set to a custom position on screen

Tags: java, android, keyboard

I want to create a custom Android keyboard. The requirements are quite simple:

1. The keyboard should not cover the full width of the screen.
2. The keyboard should be located to the bottom right corner of the screen.

I have managed to achieve the first requirement by changing the layout width to `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`. Now the keyboard is exactly how I want it but the problem is that it is located to the bottom left corner of the screen as shown below.
[image]

Is there any way that I can move it to the right end of the bottom section of the screen?

Please find below my code.

Here is my layout xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/keyboard_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:keyPreviewLayout="@layout/key_preview"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@color/black">
</android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView>
```

This is my keyboard layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Keyboard xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:keyWidth="50dp"
    android:horizontalGap="0dp"
    android:verticalGap="0dp"
    android:keyHeight="40dp">

    <Row>
        <Key android:codes="45" android:keyLabel="-"/> 
        <Key android:codes="47" android:keyLabel="/"/>
        <Key android:codes="120" android:keyLabel="x"/>
    </Row>

    <Row>
        <Key android:codes="55" android:keyLabel="7"/>
        <Key android:codes="56" android:keyLabel="8"/>
        <Key android:codes="57" android:keyLabel="9"/>
    </Row>

    <Row>
        <Key android:codes="52" android:keyLabel="4"/>
        <Key android:codes="53" android:keyLabel="5"/>
        <Key android:codes="54" android:keyLabel="6"/>
    </Row>

    <Row>
        <Key android:codes="49" android:keyLabel="1"/>
        <Key android:codes="50" android:keyLabel="2"/>
        <Key android:codes="51" android:keyLabel="3"/>
    </Row>

    <Row>
        <Key android:keyOutputText="mm " android:keyLabel="mm"/>
        <Key android:codes="48" android:keyLabel="0"/>
        <Key android:codes="46" android:keyLabel="."/>
    </Row>
</Keyboard>
```

And this is my manifest:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.customkeyboard.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.customkeyboard.NoActionBar">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: Have you tried `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"` or `android:layout_gravity="right"`?

Comment: I tried both but they didn't worked. I realised (and correct me if I am wrong) that in order those to work the `<android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView>` should be enclosed to `RelativeLayout` but when I try it the keyboard simply crashes